# DNS name server error

Tags: google-search-console, dns

I am getting DNS error on google webmaster tools. And even after testing with this http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=ansoftsys.com&timestamp=1372108107&view=1

Name Server details
[image]
Here is a screenshot my DNS management page
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJPDy.jpg]

How to solve this issue?

And my DNS error image is below generated from this link http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=ansoftsys.com&timestamp=1372108107&view=1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to view the details of the images...

When I ran a DNS report here:  [DNS Health Check](http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/domain_check.php)

That's indicating that the nameservers are missing `A` records, the IP address (`50.23.136.173`) of the nameserver `dns1.bigrock.in` is having intermittent connection timeouts too,  the SOA EXPIRE value is very low, and there are problems with your mail servers...

It appears to be a combination of DNS setting issues, and possibly DNS service issues as well. You should contact their tech support ASAP and have them run some external DNS checks, like the one above.

Note that any DNS changes will take approximately 24-72 to propagate through the Internet.

Comment: these images are here http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndl93.jpg   and http://i.stack.imgur.com/2OH6h.jpg

Comment: Thank you for this, i have contacted to my server support, they said it will be fine after 2-3 days.

Comment: No problem. BTW, this could be contributing to the issues you're having with AdSense, if Google can't reach your site that is. Try resubmitting after the DNS issues are resolved.